# How to create a views normal menu based on a contextual filter

Tags: views, tokens

In drupal7 I can create a views menu and path easily. What I would like to do is create an automatic path and normal menu based on a field [year] that is associated with a specific node type, using a date token.

Example: 
url: /student/2012      with 2012 being the field that gets update automatically
menu undergrad/2012     main menu (unergrad) with sub-menu (2012) which is a field